# Android, IntentService dies when app is killed

Tags: android

I have an intent service that notifies the user. Its onHandleIntent is as follows:

```
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(final Intent workIntent) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        try{
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
            mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            mBuilder.setContentTitle(String.valueOf(i) + "times called!");
            mBuilder.setContentText("Hi, This is Android Notification Detail!");

            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            mNotificationManager.notify(i, mBuilder.build());
        }catch(InterruptedException ex){}
    }
}
```

This approach works perfectly if the app is active or even when it is in the background, stopped state.

But when i kill the app (swiping left), service execution stops.Even if it was not finished yet. How can i overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run your `IntentService` as foreground to make it persist even when you close app from recents.
[Service.startForeground](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification))

```
 @Override
protected void onHandleIntent(final Intent workIntent) {
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    try{
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle(String.valueOf(i) + "times called!");
        mBuilder.setContentText("Hi, This is Android Notification Detail!");

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // here you can start it as foreground
        startForeground(i, mBuilder.build());
    }catch(InterruptedException ex){}
}
```

If you use `i` to create the notification then you will be creating multiple notifications(in you case 10 different) which is not good. You can use some constant value instead of i in `startForeground`.
Also before using IntentService in real application make sure it is the right choice. Here is short discussion about different type of threading in android [Things to consider before running background tasks](https://blog.yipl.com.np/things-to-consider-before-running-background-tasks-e71f00d2ad3a)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.That did really do the trick. But i have one more question. When i delete the for loop and try/catch block, code doesn't work. Why would that be?